# Horizontal line padding

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a horizontal line between two EditText widgets, but strangely the line has no padding at the bottom, so it appears "glued" to the widget that is below it.

This is my code (in the layout.xml, inside a LinearLayout with vertical orientation):

```
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="30" />
    <View android:background="#FF00FF00" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip" />
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:maxLines="8" />
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

I'd like to add some padding below the line. I tried with android:paddingBottom in the View widget, and with android:paddingTop in the below EditText widget, but the result is the same (it's ignored).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using padding use **margin**.
Use the following property in xml:

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
```

Hope this will solve your problem...:)

Answer (score 3):

Use a margin instead. Padding is the area around the content inside a View. If you give padding to an EditText for instance, you increase the size of the box (the area around the text), but don't give any space around it.

Comment: You are right. I tested with android:marginBottom, as I tought it was related to android:paddingBottom, but it doesn't exist. In margin it's needed the "layout" part in the name, that is android:layout_marginBottom... that's very confusing...

Comment: It takes getting used to. The reason "layout_" is part of the name, is because the margin is part of a view's "layout parameters" and not a View's individual properties.